# Compact Flash Cards for Deva 5.8

Tags: deva, backups, compact-flash-cards, workflow

This is probably a bit specific for most people on here, but I'm looking into using compact flash cards as a mirroring solution for our Deva 5.8 at work. Does anyone know if there is a capacity limitation as to which cards can be used?

Note: I'm not concerned about speeds, I've found out the minimum specs for that [10Mb/s] and those are easily cleared. I just want to make sure I'm not going to buy the wrong cards before I try to convince the money people here to let me do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a capacity limitation.  Or at least not one within a reasonable price range of compact flash cards.  I've used anywhere from a 1gb card to a 32gb card on both the 5.8 and the Fusion 12, and I've never had a problem.  I've used a whole range of brands of cards, never had one that didn't work.  Never used anything above a 32gb card, but I don't suspect you'll be attempting to use one.  I'm using the most recent firmware, so as long as you are, I suspect you'll be pretty much fine with any card you get, assuming it meets the speed standards (as you said, 10Mb/s +).

Good luck!

BTW, nice to see a Zaxcom question here...  Don't get to answer too many of those online :-)

Comment: thanks for the info. from what i've seen, zaxcom gear is solid that there aren't many questions you CAN ask about them. lol. i just couldn't find anything on their site or the yahoo group talking about anything larger than 8 gig cards.

Comment: @Shaun - NP.  Just in case, I'll go double check it again later today.

Comment: @Colin - I stole two cards from the video guys, both 16gb (1 Lexar, 1 Sandisk). The Lexar card just wouldn't mount, no matter what I did. I had read about some people having issues with those though, so that didn't surprise me. I'm mirroring to the Sandisk now, and the unit seems pretty happy so far.